# Set Customized Validation Exception Message in JPA 2.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, internationalization, jpa-2.0

I am working on a Web Service JaxRs project where I get all the DB scripts from DBA. So first I execute that DB script to create all the tables and all the constraints on the tables attributes, in the DB itself(DB2 here) like character length etc.
Then in the project I use *Generate Entities from Table* in Eclipse which creates all the model classes.

But the main problem arises here.There is a table "USER" having an attribute username which is nullable false and userType which is max 3 characters long. These restrictions/validations/constraints are there in the DB itself but not in the Java User Model Class.Also i cannot change those Model classes and add these validations here in code in model classes.

Now while creating the user I am putting the logic for these constraints in DAO layer while saving. But instead of the prior one, I want to have mechanism for error message that a constraints has failed while saving like if the input userType provided by front-end is more than 3 char which fails the validation, using i18n.properties file or any api/framework.

Currently if any validation fails while calling EntityManager persist() and then commit() method  the code reaches the last catch(RollbackException e){} block without any specific validation exception message OR any cause of rollback exception.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do. How can I generalize this so that it can be applied to my model class & checks for the constraints in DB using JNDI lookup and give customised messages. If any further explanation is required please ask or any code snippet you  want.

Comment: if anythings is not clear please reply so that I can elaborate more.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're expecting the database to "validate" things then YOUR code will have to cater for whatever SQLException is thrown at INSERT/UPDATE. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @NeilStockton yes sure I can add SQLException in DAO layer but will taht be able to tell which validation failed while saving the object like userType max 3 char validation failed, somehow using i18n or any config/properties

Comment: The interpretation of SQLException error codes and messages is what YOUR CODE needs to interpret. Whether your JDBC driver provides enough info is a question for it; suggest you try it. The JPA implementation is nothing to do with the process other than it will send an INSERT/UPDATE statement and then throw exceptions if it fails

Comment: @NeilStockton yes I am using DB2 db & it gives certain error codes which I can interpret to see what constrain is failed like some nullable false values are left as null but it wont tell which attribute has got this error. Can i somehow generalize this so that it can be applied to any model class & checks for the contraints in DB using JNDI lookup and give customised messages

Comment: Yes, you can do that, Ankit. When you do, please open source the framework so that we can do this too. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidS yes i am working on it. But if any help or support from you guys is also there, i can work on it quickly. Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: Any updates or suggestions. Reply would be highly appreciated

Comment: It's a big question, Ankit, probably much too big for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidS is it a sarcastic comment. I simply asked what i want to do and what problem i am facing

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was sarcastic. The question "Can I somehow generalize this" must almost always be _yes_. The question "How can I" might be what you really meant, but this is too big and vague for StackOverflow. There are too many possible answers, or an answer would take too long for this format.

Comment: @DavidS i edited that. I am not aware of any solution, I searched over internet. Thats why i asked whether its possible or not. I wrote the post in much verbose because i want to explain the scenario.